# textview cannot show Intent.getStringExtra and returns Attempt to invoke virtual method void on a null object

Tags: android, android-intent, casting, textview

I am sending the Mainactivity adapter data to another Intend and then displaying it in textView but it gives me issue

Main Activity.java

```
Article m = articleList.get(position);
int catidd = (int) view.getTag();
intent.putExtra(cat_id, String.valueOf(catidd));
intent.putExtra("title", m.title);
intent.putExtra("thumbnailUrl", m.thumbnailUrl);
intent.putExtra("description", m.description);
startActivity(intent);
```

this sends the parameters to details Intent ... 
Detailview.java

```
TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_description);

final String catid = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.cat_id);
// String message = "Test";
id = catid;
//String title = intent.getExtras().getString("title");
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
// Showing progress dialog before making http request
pDialog.setMessage(this.getIntent().getStringExtra("description"));
pDialog.show();

description.setText(this.getIntent().getStringExtra("description"));
```

Now the Dialog shows the data but the description.setText gives Null exception returns Attempt to invoke virtual method void on a null object

content_detailview.xml > layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3.2"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.6"
        android:background="@drawable/articleimg"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"></RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3.24"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="10"
        >



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="4"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detail_description"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:padding="3dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detail_title"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/floating"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:background="@drawable/dots"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    />
```

Comment: `getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.cat_id);`

Answer (score 0):

I was calling setContentView() after findViewById() which was wrong.

Until the setContentView() has taken place, view isn't in place, and so it can't be interrogated for what it contains. Move the last line up a bit, and it should solve the problem.

Corrected

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_second);
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewdata);
textView.setText(message);
```